# Android SQLite Refreshing data on view after modification

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I have an activity, `GridView`, that displays the data from my database. When user selects an `Account` it will load up another activity `AccountManager` which will contain all details of the selected item from `GridView` and allow the user to manage it from there (Modify, Delete and whatnot).

PROBLEM:

When user modifies the `Account` the modifications made do not show up in `AccountManager` and instead still shows the initial data from `GridView`. My guess is it's because the data linked to `AccountManager` from `GridView` isn't directly linked to the database, rather I use a middle-man for it so the data is in a way static and separate from the database.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to update the data on `AccountManager` without having to change my code. If so how do I do this, if not what method would allow me to get the data on `AccountManager` to be linked to the data in my database so any modifications will reflect on `AccountManager` immediately after modification.

How I pass data from `GridView` to `AccountManager`

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                                                long id) {
     try {
    SQLiteCursor cr = (SQLiteCursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colName));
    int amount = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colAmount));
    String purpose = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colPurpose));
    String Terms = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colTermsClass));
    String Status = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colStatClass));
    String date = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colDate));
    String editdate = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colEditDate));
    Account acc = new Account(name, amount, purpose,     db.GetTermsID(Terms),date,editdate,db.GetStatID(Status));
    acc.SetID((int) id);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(AccountManager.this, AccountDetails.class);
myIntent.putExtra("AccountObject", acc);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

  }
 }
}
```

How I retrieve the data from `GridView` in `AccountManager`

```
final Account Acc = (Account) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AccountObject");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CursorLoader http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

or a ContentObserver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Notifying the URI when the data are changed in the ContentProvider ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html ), will fire onLoadFinished or onChange of the CursorLoader and ContentObserver respectively

Comment: Very interesting. Will definitely look into this now, specifically ContentObserver. I'll get back to you once I've managed to implement it into my code properly, thank you.