# How to know if contact / phonebook list or database is updated android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contentobserver

I have implemented a sync adapter which sends all my contacts over the server.
But now I am faced with the issue that how the system can respond if it contact list has been updated.

I used the content observer to find out but it seems to be limited to activity lifecycle.

This is my code:

```
class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        this.onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

        Log.e("change   ", "contact");

    }
}
```

To register it:

```
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI, false, new MyObserver(new Handler()));
```

Isn't there any broadcast to notify about it.

Or I have to make a service for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLite Refreshing data on view after modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812897/android-sqlite-refreshing-data-on-view-after-modification)

Comment: Do you even understand what I am asking for?? Have you understood the question?

Comment: What I understood is that you have some data and you want to get notified when the data change. You used a ContentObserver for that but you want to know how this ContentObserver can be notified. If this is not what you mean, I apologise, it would help if you rephrase the question.

Comment: broadcast to notify what? what do you mean?

Comment: How to know if a contact has been added or deleted in the android phonebook irrespective of the application?

Comment: try ContentObserver + CursorJoiner

Comment: did you found any broadcast ?

Comment: @MateenChaudhry nopes, there are workarounds on how to achieve it

Comment: @WISHYca you please tell what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to run a service as follows

```
public class ContactService extends Service {

MyObserver observer;
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    System.out.println("service created");
    observer=new MyObserver(new Handler());
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, false, observer);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Then you will notify when ever contact data is changed.